# 0-1 knapSnack problem with negetive numbers

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, graph-algorithm, knapsack-problem

Given an array of positive and negative numbers, find if we can choose some of them and sum them in a way that the final sum is zero. (any non zero number will do).

We have weights of them and values.

I believe this is a version of the 0-1 knapsack problem.
the sample input and output:

```
4 - weight - percent
+ 50 30
+ 80 1
- 20 30
- 30 30
```

```
yes
```

This is the code I wrote for it, but somehow I can't figure out why this won't work:
I'm getting the output 0 for it (and I should be getting 1000, choosing the first, third and fourth one).
Is there any way to solve the knapsack problem with negative values?

```
def knapSack(W , wt , val , n): 
    if n == 0 : 
        return 0
    if (wt[n-1] > W): 
        return knapSack(W , wt , val , n-1) 
    else: 
        return max(val[n-1] + knapSack(W-wt[n-1] , wt , val , n-1), knapSack(W , wt , val , n-1)) 

val = [80, 50, -20, -30] 
wt = [ 1,30, 30, 30] 
W = 0
n = len(val) 
print(knapSack(W, wt, val, n))
```

Anyone has any idea how should I change this in order to be working??

Comment: What does it mean to neutralize them? Can you give more definition?

Comment: I will edit the question. I meant can we choose some of them and mix them in a way that the final mix is not acidic or basic. @justhalf

Comment: @MJane are you limiting how many we mix ? (for example in some cases 3 acids and 2 bases may end up neutralizing while other combinations do not)

Comment: No limits. just say if you can mix some (any non zero number will do)  @KaranShishoo

Comment: So, you mean the sum of all weight x percent of acids that we take should be equal to the sum of all weight x percent of bases that we take? If so, please put that in the question, too.

Comment: No, the sum of some of the weightpercent of acids that we take should be equal to the sum of some weight percent of bases that we take? @justhalf

Comment: Then what do you mean by the final mix is not acidic or basic?

Comment: I mean the amount of acid you mix and the amount of base you mix should be equal so that it's the final mix would be neutral @justhalf

Comment: What the max count of acids / bases?

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk ١ ≤ n ≤ 20

Comment: Just want to note, that there is 2^n - 1 combinations of acids / bases. And you have to check them all.

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk yes that did work out. The solution was to use brute force. The code is the answer bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by no ways efficient but it seemed to be the simplest method of seeing if any combination of acids and bases would cancel out. (I did not use the knapsack approach)

For each (the acids and the bases) create an array that contains their amount. In the case of your example these arrays would be - `acid = [1500, 80]` and `base = [600, 900]`. Getting these arrays depends on your input format.

once you have these arrays you can do the following -

```
def SumOfSubsets(arr): 
    Allsums = []
    for number in arr:
        Placeholder = Allsums[:]
        Allsums.append(number)
        for sum in Placeholder:
            Allsums.append(sum + number)

    return(Allsums)

AcidList = SumOfSubsets(acid)
BaseList = SumOfSubsets(base)

for acids in AcidList:
    if acids in BaseList:
        print("can be neutralized")
```

*Note that by using this approach you do not know what combinations of acids and bases are needed to achieve the neutralization. You can get this combination by using another function if needed.

Comment: I don't need to know what combination. but apparently, this only works for some test cases.  8 out of 25. others are `WRONG ANSWER` in the online judge. but I'll try to figure out how to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: This is using the brute force algorithm if I got it correctly. right?

Comment: @MJane, yes this looks at all possible combinations of sums of acids and bases before seeing if any match up

Comment: @MJane, could you please tell me what was wrong with my code ?

Comment: I added this piece of code :

`found = False
for acids in AcidList:
    if acids in BaseList:
        found = True
        print("yes")
        break

if(found == False):
    print("no")`
and when I added `break` it worked. nothing wrong with your code.